# How can I write the code to append all of the items(XPages)?

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-notes

I have many documents in Notes, all of the  documents have a different form, like this picture :

(possibly like pic 1,  pic 2, or pic 3)

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I write the code in Xpages?

use the "computed field"? Or use the "input text"?

I used the "input text".But only for one item, not for all.

```
var doc = purchase.getDocument();
var A0 = doc.getItemValueString("DAY_A0");
if(A0 != 0){
    return "Division processing";
}
```

If the form not only has one item, like the pics. How can I write the code to append all of the items?

Comment: Look at the xp:repeat control

Answer (score 1):

I'm making the following assumptions here:

- You have 10 fields in the document with numbers that might or might not be > 0
- The 11th value (Total) shall be computed
- You want to show one document at a time, not a list
- You know how to add a data source to a page

### Version 1:

- Create a regular XPages form, use the wizard when adding the document data source. It now would show also the field with 0 values
- Click on each ROW and change visibility property to computed (make sure you hit the row, not the cell or field) and add a visibility formula based on the field oof that row. Something like `doc.DAY_A0 > 0`
- Add a computed field where you add the values of all 11 fields
- done

### Version 2:

- in the page open event, get a handle on the document and compute a scoped variable that only contains the values you are interested in. Could be messy since you need a label (that is not your field name) and a value
- Use a repeat control to render the values

Hope that helps